# v8_*_cc.pdb files are missing. How do I get them?

Tags: windows, build, static, v8, pdb-files

(I am working with Windows 10)

I need to update V8 in a project that uses V8 5.8 to V8 7.9.
In the project with the old library I get these files: v8_*.lib, v8_*_cc.pdb, natives_blob.bin and snapshot_blob.bin

I have managed to build V8 7.9, but I do not get the v8_*_cc.pdb files.
How do I create these files? Thanks!

I followed the proceure described [here](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/how-to-build-v8-on-windows-and-not-go-mad-6347c69aacd4).
This got me the .bin and .lib files. but not the .pdb files.

Comment: Is the version 7.9 required strictly? You can get other built versions and debug databases with using nuget.

Comment: @273K I need V8 >= 7.9. How can I do this nuget thing???